# Match a url with quety string

Tags: regex

I'm pretty new to regex.
I researched a lot, but I can't figure out the problem.

I have this url
`https://kompozitor.fr/thenotebar/?s=test`.

The query string `?s=` is the search parameter on my blog.

I'd like to write a regex expression that matches only
`/thenotebar/?s=`
and any parameter given to the search engine.

I tried a few things like `/thenotebar/\?s=(.*)`
,but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *it won't work*? What does it do? What do you see? Share the code.

Comment: This regex expression is used in worpress to activate the run of a plugin... If the url of the page matches this expression, then the plugin will run, otherwise it won't... I used this on many other urls that are actually permalinks, without any query string. So I don't know how to tell wordpress to trigger the plugin if it finds /thenotebar/?s= followed by any caracter chain

Comment: Could you share the relevant documentation? Is it https://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/?

Comment: Again, how doesn't it work? What string do you pass? What should the regex match/extract?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need the *"thenotebar/?s="* and at least one character in the parameters.

Try to use this regex for it.

```
/\/thenotebar\/\?s=.(.*)/g
```

In your regex, you miss the **'\'** before the **'/'**, probably this is the reason, it not works. You need a dot before **(.*)**. This means you need at least one character as parameter. You need it? Leave this extra dot if you only check the *"/thenotebar/?s="* string.

Comment: Hi Actually, the plugin I'm using is called swift performance light and it used a slightly modified regex which is the reason why it wouldn't work. With your message and reading deeper in the documentation of this plugin I found the solution. I have a parameter that just allows me to check the query string. The syntax is  #s=.(.*)#   works perfectly now thanks for your help !

Comment: @KompozitorTheNoteBar you can answer your own question so others that encounter the same issue in the future will not need to read all the comments.